# C# Multilanguage messagebox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resources, messagebox, multilingual

I would like my messagebox to show information according to language slected by user. I change all button and label text according to lanugage button click. But how can I make my messagebox to display different info based on this language button click? For example if I have another button and when I click it, proper messagebox is displayed, I would like this messagebox to be displayed in different languages for different user choice. I have my all my text in resource. Bellow is my code.

```
private void btnLngEnglish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");
        Assembly a = Assembly.Load("read_display");
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("read_display.language.languageRes", a);
        button7.Text = rm.GetString("file", ci);
        button4.Text = rm.GetString("timecount", ci);
        button6.Text = rm.GetString("daterange", ci);
        button3.Text = rm.GetString("specdate", ci);
        button1.Text = rm.GetString("phrasesearch", ci);
        button5.Text = rm.GetString("higherval", ci);
        label3.Text = rm.GetString("langsel", ci);
        label5.Text = rm.GetString("rowcount", ci);
        label4.Text = rm.GetString("timeElapsed", ci);
        label1.Text = rm.GetString("filterdate", ci);
        label2.Text = rm.GetString("hide", ci);
    }

    private void btnLangPolish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("pl-PL");
        Assembly a = Assembly.Load("read_display");
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("read_display.language.languageResPL", a);
        button7.Text = rm.GetString("file", ci);
        button4.Text = rm.GetString("timecount", ci);
        button6.Text = rm.GetString("daterange", ci);
        button3.Text = rm.GetString("specdate", ci);
        button1.Text = rm.GetString("phrasesearch", ci);
        button5.Text = rm.GetString("higherval", ci);
        label3.Text = rm.GetString("langsel", ci);
        label5.Text = rm.GetString("rowcount", ci);
        label4.Text = rm.GetString("timeElapsed", ci);
        label1.Text = rm.GetString("filterdate", ci);
        label2.Text = rm.GetString("hide", ci);
    }
```

EDIT:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchString = textBox8.Text;
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox8.Text))
        {
            //Here I would like to diplay messages in two different language, based on previous language button click. Can I do it??
            MessageBox.Show("Enter value to filter");
        }
        else
        {
            bool found = false;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Contains(searchString))
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.MediumPurple;
                    row.Selected = true;
                    found = true;
                }
                if (row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Contains(searchString))
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.MediumPurple;
                    found = true;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
            {
                //Here I would like to do same thing
                MessageBox.Show("Value was not found");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try moving the message in Resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd change the names of all those buttons to reflect what they actually are. This is more a piece of advice.

Either way, can't you just call `MessageBox.Show(rm.GetString("messageboxData", ci))`?

EDIT1 (see comments):
What I mean is something on the lines of:

```
class MyClass
{
    CultureInfo currentCultureInfo;
    public MyClass()
    {
        //defaulting to en-US
        currentCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    }

    public void SetLanguageToEnglish()
    {
        currentCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    }

    public void SetLanguageToItalian()
    {
        currentCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("it-IT");
    }

    public string GetTranslation(string s)
    {
        //By the way, you should to the same to 'a' and 'rm', since they don't need to be instantiated each time. But I'll use your code to avoid confusion.
        Assembly a = Assembly.Load("read_display");
        ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("read_display.language.languageRes", a);
        return rm.GetString(s, currentCultureInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I can't do it like this. This two buttons are done to change overal language in my app. When I click them all buttons and labels displayed on main page change from one lang to another. I will edit the code to show exactly where I would like to change this messagebox.

Comment: Wait, I think I understand. You could store a global reference to a CultureInfo, say "currentCultureInfo", which is set inside the button click events. Then you can access the data from outside by calling rm.GetString("messageboxData", currentCultureInfo).

Comment: GetTranslation was just an example. You can replace it with btnLngEnglish_Click. However, you need to change that method and make it call SetLanguageToWhatever (you could also make a SetLanguage function which accepts a string as parameter, or change currentCultureInfo directly. The point is the same) first of all. Then keep your code the same, but instead of 'ci' use currentCultureInfo. I hope I made myself clear, but if you still need some help don't hesitate to ask me, and I'll post an example using your current code.

Comment: Ok, I manage to fix it. Thank You very much for help. Now I can changee rest of my messageboxes. :)